# Writing File with ARGV Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, argv

I am trying to get my output to look like this:

```
$100.00
teddy bear,$5.00
shirt,$22.75
pants,$50.35
```

However, when I run the command to write the input to the file, I get the wrong format:

```
ruby start.rb '$100.00\nteddy bear,$5.00\nshirt,$22.75\npants,$50.35'
```

start.rb:

```
input  = ARGV.first
File.open('./data_files/list.txt', 'w') {|file| file.write(input)}
```

Final output (in my data_files/list.txt file):

```
$100.00\nteddy bear,$5.00\nshirt,$22.75\npants,$50.35
```

Any idea how to write the file so it appears in the correct format?

Thanks

Comment: If you actually desire an answer please post all relevant code/files.

Comment: At some point you'll want to take input from STDIN, though since you don't really transform anything here, I'm confused as to what this program actually does. `echo ... > ./data_files/list.txt` would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell doesn't recognize `\n` as a newline in regular single-quoted strings; you are passing literal backslash-n to Ruby. (And Ruby doesn't process input strings the way it does literal strings in Ruby code.)

If your shell is bash, you can use `$'...'` ANSI strings instead:

```
ruby start.rb $'$100.00\nteddy bear,$5.00\nshirt,$22.75\npants,$50.35'
```

Otherwise, you can use literal newlines:

```
ruby start.rb '$100.00
teddy bear,$5.00
shirt,$22.75
pants,$50.35'
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! Great explanation (and I just tried it and it works!). Will accept in 9 minutes